# ASP.NET MVC - Castle ActiveRecord - Show SQL queries

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) as my persistance layer.

I want to know if it's possible to show the SQL queries being executed on my MySQL server.

I know it's possible in a Web application using the "show_sql" property in the Castle XML configuration file, but I don't know how to do it using a Web application, since I don't have access to the Console.

I think I can use log4net to do it, but after some research using Google, I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: are you already using log4net?

Comment: No, but I know that you can configure Castle ActiveRecord to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Application_Start:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("/log4net.config")));
```

Then you need a log4net.config in your root, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net" >
        <param name="File" value="log.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="7" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

[Here's a sample app](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/MVCActiveRecordIntegration/) you can use as reference.

Comment: That did it! The log is a little bit too verbose for my taste, but it does the job nevertheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tutorial on how to configure log4net for ASP.NET, it's all the same for MVC:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Log4Net_Configuration.aspx

And here is how to configure NHibernate to output SQL to log4net
http://www.davesquared.net/2008/01/viewing-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html